# Possibility n independent random events ocuuring per year? An event is any piece of equipment failing per year

Tags: probability, independence, conditional, engineering-statistics

So I am an engineer. We have a method at our organization of defining the probability of an equipment failure based on frequency of occurrence. So for example we may categorize a piece of equipment failing falling under a category of failing once in between 1 to 10 years or 10 to 100 years, or even less than 1 year for high risk items.

I felt this fit well into a Poisson Distribution to do so in order to determine a percentage for the probability of exactly n of these independent random variables of occurring once per year.

$$

\begin{array}{llllll}
Machinery & \text{Frequency of Occurance} & \text{Assumption Frequecy per Year (Expected Value)} & \text{Probability via Poisson Distribution of Occuring Once Per Year Pr(k=1)} & \text{Probability via Poisson Distribution of Occuring Once or More Per Year (Pr(k>=1)} & \text{Probability via Poisson Distribution of Not Ocuuring Per Year Pr(k=0)} \\
A         & \text{1/10yr to 1/100yr}      & 0.02                                          & 0.019603973466135100                                                   & 0.000197353227109676                                                             & 0.980198673306755                                                     \\
B         & \text{1/10yr to 1/100yr}      & 0.02                                          & 0.019603973466135100                                                   & 0.000197353227109676                                                             & 0.980198673306755                                                     \\
C         & \text{1/10yr to 1/100yr}      & 0.02                                          & 0.019603973466135100                                                   & 0.000197353227109676                                                             & 0.980198673306755                                                     \\
D         & \text{1/yr to 1/10yr}         & 0.20                                          & 0.163746150615596000                                                   & 0.017523096306421800                                                             & 0.818730753077982                                                     \\
E         & \text{1/yr to 1/10yr}         & 0.20                                          & 0.163746150615596000                                                   & 0.017523096306421800                                                             & 0.818730753077982                                                     \\
F         & \text{1/yr to 1/10yr}         & 0.20                                          & 0.163746150615596000                                                   & 0.017523096306421800                                                             & 0.818730753077982                                                     \\
G         & \text{1/10yr to 1/100yr}      & 0.02                                          & 0.019603973466135100                                                   & 0.000197353227109676                                                             & 0.980198673306755                                                     \\
H         & \text{1/10yr to 1/100yr}      & 0.02                                          & 0.019603973466135100                                                   & 0.000197353227109676                                                             & 0.980198673306755                                                     \\
I         & \text{1/10yr to 1/100yr}      & 0.02                                          & 0.019603973466135100                                                   & 0.000197353227109676                                                             & 0.980198673306755                                                     \\
J         & \text{1/10yr to 1/100yr}      & 0.02                                          & 0.019603973466135100                                                   & 0.000197353227109676                                                             & 0.980198673306755                                                     \\
K         & \text{1/100yr to 1/1000yr}    & 0.002                                         & 0.001996003997334670                                                   & 0.000001997335332238                                                             & 0.998001998667333                                                     \\
L         & \text{1/100yr to 1/1000yr}    & 0.002                                         & 0.001996003997334670                                                   & 0.000001997335332238                                                             & 0.998001998667333                                                     \\
M         & \text{1/100yr to 1/1000yr}    & 0.002                                         & 0.001996003997334670                                                   & 0.000001997335332238                                                             & 0.998001998667333                                                     \\
N         & \text{1/yr to 1/10yr}         & 0.20                                          & 0.163746150615596000                                                   & 0.017523096306421800                                                             & 0.818730753077982                                                     \\
O         & \text{1/100yr to 1/1000yr}    & 0.002                                         & 0.001996003997334670                                                   & 0.000001997335332238                                                             & 0.998001998667333                                                    
\end{array}
$$

Can someone check where logic wrong with my math? I don't think I am right because this does not converge to 1 as the sample size increases to infinity? Where X = Event occurring once in a year and X' = Event not occurring in a year.

$$
 \Pr\left[\text{One event occurring per year} \right] = \Pr \left[ A | B' \cap C' \cap D' \cap...\right] + \Pr \left[ B | A' \cap C' \cap D' \cap...\right]+ \Pr \left[ C | A' \cap B' \cap D' \cap...\right]+ ...=\frac{\Pr\left[A \cap B' \cap C' \cap D' \cap... \right]}{\Pr\left[ A  \right]}+\frac{\Pr\left[ B \cap A' \cap C' \cap D' \cap...\right]}{\Pr\left[ B\right]}+\frac{\Pr\left[C \cap A' \cap B' \cap D' \cap... \right]}{\Pr\left[ C\right]}+...= \Pr[B']\cdot\Pr[C']\cdot Pr[D']\cdot...+\Pr[B']\cdot\Pr[C']\cdot Pr[D']\cdot...+\Pr[A']\cdot\Pr[B']\cdot Pr[D']\cdot...+...
$$

I am looking for the probability that exactly n events occur in a year. An event would be any equipment failure. Realistically, the event would only occur once per piece of equipment. I did use the poisson distribution for calculating probabilities for each piece of equipment as shown by my chart. I wondering as an overview for all pieces of equipment am I able to determine a probability of any one piece of equipment failing per year? ... any two failing per year?

I was a stats major many moons ago and I am employed now as a mechanical engineer. So my logic is probably off here.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear: are you asking for the chance that *exactly* $n$ events occur in a year or that *at least* $n$ events occur?  And would an event be "any equipment failure" or would it be "one or more failures of a given machine," so that $n$ counts the number of machines that fail, regardless of how many times each fails?  And since you state you are using a Poisson distribution, why not use the formulas for its probabilities?

Comment: I am looking for the probability that exactly n events occur in a year. An event would be any equipment failure. Realistically, the event would only occur once per piece of equipment. I did use the poisson distribution for calculating probabilities for each piece of equipment as shown by my chart. I wondering as an overview for all pieces of equipment am I able to determine a probability of any one machine failing per year? ... any two failing per year?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396214/probability-of-at-least-n-events-occuring I believe I found what I was looking for on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can model each piece of equipment using [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). Then, the probability that this piece of equipment will fail after time $t$ is

$$p_i(t) = 1 - \exp(- t / \tau_i)$$

where $\tau_i$ is the expected fail time for this piece of equipment. You seem to be interested $t = t_0 = 1$ year. Compute probabilities via

$$P_i = p_i(t_0)$$

Next, we want to know the probability that exactly $n$ out of $N$ events will occur. To do so, we need to go over all ways to select $n$ events out of $N$, compute the probability of occurence for each of the combinations, and then sum them up. Let $s$ be a vector of 1s and 0s, indicating which pieces of equipment failed. We require that $\sum_i s_i = n$. Then if, we know $s$, the probability of that situation is
$$P[s] = \prod_{i=1}^N P_i^{s_i} (1 - P_i)^{1-s_i}$$
That is, we multiply the result by $P_i$ if $s_i=1$, otherwise we multiply the result by $1 - P_i$. Finally, to find the probability of exactly $N$ events, we need to sum $P[s]$ over all combinations $s \in S(n, N)$.

$$P[N] = \sum_{s \in S(n, N)} P[s]$$

If $N$ is not too large (10-20), you may be able to write a brute-force code to compute $P[N]$ and get an answer within a few seconds. However, if $N >> 20$, you will need to optimize the code for computing the result, so that you have a chance of getting the answer within the age of the universe :D. I can provide a python code for this solution if you feel that it is necessary.